# Independent cascade modelling in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to study network diffusion. I took the code form [this](http://php.scripts.psu.edu/hxc249/code_segments/independent_cascade.py). However, I would like to see if there's any potential to optimize the code to be faster and clearer. This is what I'm trying to do.

In a node, get all the successors and loop through to get the property in an edge to see if the probability is more than random number from (0,1). If yes, then that node should be activated, if no then move on. I use iGraph library for any graph manipulation.

```
def independent_cascade_igraph(G, seeds, steps=0):
    # init activation probabilities
    for e in G.es():
        if 'act_prob' not in e.attributes():
            e['act_prob'] = 0.1
        elif e['act_prob'] > 1:
            raise Exception("edge activation probability:", e['act_prob'], "cannot be larger than 1")

    # perform diffusion
    A = copy.deepcopy(seeds)  # prevent side effect
    if steps <= 0:
        # perform diffusion until no more nodes can be activated
        return _diffuse_all(G, A)
    # perform diffusion for at most "steps" rounds
    return _diffuse_k_rounds(G, A, steps)

def _diffuse_all(G, A):
    tried_edges = set()
    layer_i_nodes = [ ]
    layer_i_nodes.append([i for i in A])  # prevent side effect
    while True:
        len_old = len(A)
        (A, activated_nodes_of_this_round, cur_tried_edges) = _diffuse_one_round(G, A, tried_edges)
        layer_i_nodes.append(activated_nodes_of_this_round)
        tried_edges = tried_edges.union(cur_tried_edges)
        if len(A) == len_old:
            break
    return layer_i_nodes

def _diffuse_k_rounds(G, A, steps):
    tried_edges = set()
    layer_i_nodes = [ ]
    layer_i_nodes.append([i for i in A])
    while steps > 0 and len(A) < G.vcount():
        len_old = len(A)
        (A, activated_nodes_of_this_round, cur_tried_edges) = _diffuse_one_round(G, A, tried_edges)
        layer_i_nodes.append(activated_nodes_of_this_round)
        tried_edges = tried_edges.union(cur_tried_edges)
        if len(A) == len_old:
            break
        steps -= 1
    return layer_i_nodes

def _diffuse_one_round(G, A, tried_edges):
    activated_nodes_of_this_round = set()
    cur_tried_edges = set()
    for s in A:
        for nb in G.successors(s):
            if nb in A or (s, nb) in tried_edges or (s, nb) in cur_tried_edges:
                continue
            if _prop_success(G, s, nb):
                activated_nodes_of_this_round.add(nb)
            cur_tried_edges.add((s, nb))
    activated_nodes_of_this_round = list(activated_nodes_of_this_round)
    A.extend(activated_nodes_of_this_round)
    return A, activated_nodes_of_this_round, cur_tried_edges

def _prop_success(G, src, dest):
    '''
    act_prob = 0.1
    for e in G.es():
        if (src, dest) == e.tuple:
            act_prob = e['act_prob']
            break
    '''
    return random.random() <= 0.1
```

And this is how you test the code. The idea is to test how far your message can go in your network.

```
test_g = Graph([(1,2), (2,1), (1,3), (3,1), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4), (3,5), (4,5), (5,6), (6,5), (6,4), (6,2)], directed=True)
test_g.es['act_prob'] = [.5, .5, .2, .2, .3, .5, .1, .2, .2, .6, .6, .3, .4]

independent_cascade_igraph(test_g, [1])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, I'd add the activation probability as a parameter of the `independant_cascade_igraph` function. That way you are assured that the attribute is defined on the edges and can also manage default value. Thus you are not required to know the name of the edge attribute  in advance to use your function:

```
def independent_cascade_igraph(G, seeds, probs=0.1, steps=0):
    # init activation probabilities
    if (type(probs) in (int, float) and (0 <= probs <= 1)) or all(0 <= p <= 1 for p in probs):
        G.es['act_prob'] = probs
    else:
        raise Exception("Found probability outside of [0, 1]")
```

However I recommend you define your own `Exception` so further handling is better performed.

The copy of the seeds can be simplified since it represent vertices which are always integers:

```
    # perform diffusion
    A = seeds[:] # prevent side effect
```

The two functions for the diffusion hold the same logic, only the stopping condition differ. DRY:

```
    if steps <= 0:
        # perform diffusion until no more nodes can be activated
        return _diffuse(G, A)
    # perform diffusion for at most "steps" rounds
    return _diffuse(G, A, steps)

def _diffuse(G, A, steps=None):
    vertices = G.vcount()
    tried_edges = set()
    layer_i_nodes = [A[:]]
    while True:
        len_old = len(A)
        activated_nodes_round, tried_edges_round = _diffuse_one_round(G, A, tried_edges)
        layer_i_nodes.append(activated_nodes_round)
        tried_edges |= tried_edges_round
        if len(A) == len_old:
            break
        if steps is not None:
            steps -= 1
            if not steps or len(A) >= vertices:
                break
    return layer_i_nodes
```

Updating the `set` is more idiomatic.

You don't need to return `A` from `_diffuse_one_round` since it is modified in place:

```
def _diffuse_one_round(G, A, tried_edges):
    cur_tried_edges = set((s, nb) for s in A for nb in G.successors(s)) - tried_edges
    activated_nodes = [node for src,node in cur_tried_edges if node not in A and _prop_success(G, src, node)]
    A.extend(set(activated_nodes))
    return activated_nodes, cur_tried_edges
```

I'm going to assume that you actually what to retrieve the attribute here, orherwise just remove this function, all the attribute handling at the beginning and use `random.random() <= 0.1` in the list comprehension:

```
def _prop_success(G, src, dest, r=random.random): # Faster access to random
    id = G.get_eid(src, dest)
    return r() <= G.es[id]['act_prob']
```

You can then test with:

```
test_g = Graph([(1,2), (2,1), (1,3), (3,1), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4), (3,5), (4,5), (5,6), (6,5), (6,4), (6,2)], directed=True)
independent_cascade_igraph(test_g, [1], [.5, .5, .2, .2, .3, .5, .1, .2, .2, .6, .6, .3, .4])
```

---

Note however that the very purpose of `_diffuse_one_round`, its gained simplicity and the fact that it has the non-trivial side effect of modifying `A` in place, all play in favor of merging it in the `while` loop of `_diffuse` instead of keeping it:

```
def _diffuse(G, active_nodes, steps=None):
    vertices = G.vcount()
    visited_edges = set()
    activation_history = [active_nodes[:]]
    previous_len = None
    while previous_len != len(active_nodes) and (step is None or step):
        previous_len = len(active_nodes)
        current_edges = set((begin, end) for begin in active_nodes for end in G.successors(begin)) - visited_edges
        activated_nodes = [node for src,node in current_edges if node not in A and _prop_success(G, src, node)]
        active_nodes.extend(set(activated_nodes))
        activation_history.append(activated_nodes)
        visited_edges |= current_edges
        if steps is not None:
            steps -= 1
    return activation_history
```

I also renamed some variables to make the code more explicit, which you should do more often.

Comment: When I run the code I get this error.
`
ipython-input-56-1f4df92d7719> in _diffuse_one_round(G, A, tried_edges)
      1 def _diffuse_one_round(G, A, tried_edges):
----> 2     cur_tried_edges = set((s, nb) for nb in G.successors(s) for s in A) - tried_edges
      3     activated_nodes = [node for node in cur_tried_edges if _prop_success(G, node)]
      4     A.extend(activated_nodes)
      5     return activated_nodes, cur_tried_edges

NameError: global name 's' is not defined
`

Comment: @toy My bad. You need to change the order of the `for` in the `cur_tried_edges` generation. Will update the answer.

Comment: @toy I also made a mistake in `_diffuse_one_round` (which should be merged into `_diffuse`, see update) where I added edges into `A` instead of the arrival node. It is now corrected.