# Independent cascade model for networkx graphs

Tags: python, graph

Similar to this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104803/independent-cascade-modelling-in-python), I implemented the independent cascade model, but for a given [networkx](https://networkx.github.io) graph (including multigraph with parallel edges). My focus is on readability, pythonic-ness, and performance (although the problem itself is NP-hard).

I cannot wait to hear your feedback!

```
def independent_cascade_model(G: nx.Graph, seed: list, beta: float=1.0):       
    informed_nodes = {n: None for n in seed}
    updated = True

    while updated:
        for u, v, diffusion_time in G.edges(nbunch=informed_nodes, data='diffusion_time'):
            updated = False
            if informed_nodes[u] == None or informed_nodes[u] < diffusion_time:
                if random.random() < beta:
                    if v not in informed_nodes or diffusion_time < informed_nodes[v]:
                        informed_nodes[v] = diffusion_time
                        updated = True
    return informed_nodes
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can follow the problem from your code. From your naming, it seems like `seed` contains the nodes informed at `t = 0` and that `diffusion_time` is the time it takes  the information to go from `u` to `v`. Hence, we infer that the time to inform `v` is `informed_nodes[u] + diffusion_time`, and that for each seed `s`, `informed_time[s] == 0`. This is different in your code, did I misunderstand the problem?

Answer (score 3):

## Correctness / Readability

I'm not sure if this is a bug, or just an unclearness of the algorithm.

```
    while updated:
        for ... in ...:
            updated = False
            if ...:
                if ...:
                    if ...:
                        ...
                        updated = True
```

If you want to loop over the edges, until no change is made, then the `updated = False` looks like it is in the wrong place.  As it currently stands, if the last edge processed in the `for` loop fails any of the 3 if conditions, the `updated` flag is set to `False`, even if a prior edge set it to `True`.

Wouldn't the correct implementation be:

```
    while updated:
        updated = False
        for ... in ...:
            if ...:
                if ...:
                    if ...:
                        ...
                        updated = True
```

Now, for each `while` loop iteration, we start by clearing the flag.  Then, if any edge results in `updated = True`, a change has been made and the `while` loop is repeated.

If the `updated = False` was in the correct place, then the readability of the code could be improved with comments explaining why `update = True` only matters for the last edge returned by the `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use `==`/`!=` to compare to singletons like `None`, instead use `is`/`is not`.

Here is one way to restructure your conditions. This reduces the amount of nesting, which hopefully increases the overall readability.

```
import math

def independent_cascade_model(G: nx.Graph, seed: list, beta: float=1.0):       
    informed_nodes = {n: None for n in seed}
    updated = True
    while updated:
        updated = False
        for u, v, diffusion_time in G.edges(nbunch=informed_nodes, data='diffusion_time'):
            if informed_nodes.get(u, math.nan) <= diffusion_time:
                # node is already set up properly
                continue
            elif random.random() >= beta:
                continue
            elif informed_nodes.get(v, math.inf) > diffusion_time:
                informed_nodes[v] = diffusion_time
                updated = True
    return informed_nodes
```

Here I also used `dict.get` with the optional default argument set in such a way that the conditions are the right way around for missing data.

```
>>> n = 10             # works for any numeric n
>>> math.nan <= n    
# False

>>> import sys
>>> n = sys.maxsize    # works for any numeric n except for inf
>>> math.inf > n
# True
```

Just make sure you don't run into `math.inf > math.inf` -> `False` or `math.inf > math.nan` -> `False`

You should also add a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to your function explaining what it does and what the arguments are.

Comment: Using the `math.nan` and `math.inf` constants are preferable over using `float("...")` to repeatedly convert strings into the special floating point singleton values.

Comment: @AJNeufeld You are right. I did not know of this convention, but it makes sense to not constantly arse a string...